# error: Illegal instruction (core dumped) - tensorflow==2.1.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I am importing tensorflow in my ubuntu (Lenovo 110-Ideapad laptop) python using following commands-

```
(tfx-test) chandni@mxnet:~/Chandni/TFX$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

And the program exits. Kindly let me know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to downgrade to CPU 1.5.

```
#Try running
pip uninstall tensorflow
#And then
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

Then import tensorflow and let me know if the error reoccur

Comment: Thanks, this comment helped in my case. See also https://tech.amikelive.com/node-887/how-to-resolve-error-illegal-instruction-core-dumped-when-running-import-tensorflow-in-a-python-program/.